# Prevent navigation properties from being generated in Entity Framework Code Generation Tool

Tags: code-generation, entity-framework-4.3

Is there a code generation tool out there that allows me to set whether or not I want nav properties generated?

Comment: I think no, there isn't any. What is wrong with deleting navigation properties you don't want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it makes sense for the tool to create my navigation properties. I'll just delete the ones I don't care to have